# What's faster? Merge byte arrays or send separately?

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, packet

### One big array or 200 small ones?

I have objects that I turn into byte arrays with some code magic and then send those thru `DataOutputStream` over `Socket`. But, should I send those arrays separately for every object or merge them into one array and then "extract" it on the client side?

The arrays are maximum 48 bytes long, but if I have 200 objects, it means that I have total of 200 (48 bytes each let's say) arrays of bytes to send over the network, is it faster to merge them into one huge array (9600 bytes) and send it once?

---

### Current solution

Currently, I'm sending those one by one, for every object. To make them merge and then extract when received is a big job, so I rather ask professionals before doing it.

---

If there is a duplicate of the same question, then sorry, I just can't put my ideas into words to search them up. Not natively speaking English.

Comment: Depends on how you have set up things. If the underlying stream is buffered and you don't flush after each array I don't expect much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to merge multiple arrays into one. In fact there is a pattern for what you are currently doing, called scatter-gather, which is slightly more sophisticated, but in essence is about reading a data stream into multiple buffers, and writing to a data stream from multiple buffers (arrays).

Merging them together shouldn't really take much time for the data volumes you are dealing with, but seems unnecessary. If you are concerned about scalability maybe have a look at NIO, which provides a SocketChannel (which implements GatheringByteChannel) to which you can write from multiple buffers in one call.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#write-java.nio.ByteBuffer:A-

Comment: Well NIO primarily offers non-blocking IO and async IO for sockets. You also get more control on buffers etc., So you might get a little performance benefit, but the real strength is more to do with scalability. With non-blocking IO, the server doesn't need to have a separate thread for each connected client, so you can scale for many more (thousands) of concurrent connected clients, without having Thread overheads which gets very heavy. You might also want to look at the Netty library which makes NIO a bit easier.

Comment: Nice, will check it out, maybe even switch to it.